# How to use an expression in the Object literal key?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, object-literal

I have a switch^

```
  let s = "aaa"

  switch (true) {
    case s.includes('a'):
      url = 'https://a.com/wp-admin/post-new.php'
      console.log(url)
      break
    case s.includes('b'):
      url = 'https://b.com/wp-admin/post-new.php'
      console.log(url)
      break
    default:
      console.log('default')
      break
  }
```

I'm trying to change this to a literal object, but I can't figure out how to properly specify the s.includes condition as the object key

```
  const objLit = (s) => {
    const cases = {
      //s.includes('a'): 'https://a.com/wp-admin/post-new.php',
      [`${s.includes('a')}`]: 'https://a.com/wp-admin/post-new.php',
      //s.includes('b'): 'https://b.com/wp-admin/post-new.php',
      [`${s.includes('b')}`]: 'https://b.com/wp-admin/post-new.php',
    }

    let url = cases[s]
    return url

  }

  console.log(objLit(s))
```

Although this does not throw an error, it does not work.

Comment: The key is wrong; look at the object you're creating, the property names are `"false"` and maybe `"true"`. (It's also not a nice approach.)

Comment: This type of thing isn't a suitable use for an object. It's better off as an if-statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Property names are strings or Symbols.

When you use `[]` syntax, the expression is evaluated **at object creation time**.

You can't assign code that gets evaluated at lookup time. This is what `switch` and `if`/`else` are for.

In your case, since `includes()` returns a boolean, you are just creating an object with properties named `"true"` and `"false"`.

You *could* say `let url = cases.true`, but it would be a horrible hack.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to simplify the code. Too bad it's not possible :(